# Set MasSessions to SSH does not take effect

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-agent

I got a server with enabled ssh. To prevent attacks and to fit to my needs, I just need one connection at the same time to my server. So, I tried to set `MaxSessions` paramater to `1` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, restartet the daemon and it does not take effect. My server uses openSUSE 13.2

Comment: Limiting the number of connections to 1 will not prevent attacks. It will, however, sometimes cause a denial of service: when you get disconnected by a client crash or network glitch, you won't be able to log back in until the server has timed out. Don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MaxSessions parameter limits the number of **multiplexed** sessions you have on a single ssh session.

*Session multiplexing* allows to setup a single Master connection which all other connections to the same host can then reuse. This has no effect on the ability to connect again to the same host via a new network connection.

SSH has no way to limit or control multiple connections coming from different IP addresses.

You will need to use `/etc/security/limits.conf` so each user is limited to 1 session. Something like this:

```
userid  - maxlogins  1
```

Comment: OP probably wants to set `maxlogins` in `limits.conf`

Comment: do I need to restart a daemon then?

Comment: No. Active sessions will use old values. Doing a log out and back in take effect of the limits change.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me a lot. The most possible that can I do in that case.

Comment: Note the sessions here refer to tty sessions. notty are not counted.